# LINQ Convert Dictionary to Lookup

Tags: linq, dictionary, lookup

I have a variable of type `Dictionary<MyType, List<MyOtherType>>`
I want to convert it to a `Lookup<MyType, MyOtherType>`.

I wanted to use Lambda functions to first, flatten the dictionary and then convert this to Lookup using the `ToLookup()`.  I got stuck with the dictionary. I thought about using SelectMany but can't get it working.  Anyone has got an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about:

```
var lookup = dictionary.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value,
                                   (pair, Value) => new { pair.Key, Value })
                       .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

It does feel like a little bit of a waste doing this when the dictionary already has all the information grouped appropriately, but I can't see a simple way round that. Of course you could implement `ILookup<TKey, TValue>` yourself with a wrapper around the dictionary...

Comment: In my case, it didn't make sense for one module/class to be concerned with error handling of an empty list. When you have a dictionary of lists, the empty list is a bit of an anomaly, as it's probably results in a KeyNotFoundException - the ILookUp interface provides more consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 28):

Same as Jon's method, but avoiding the creation of an anonymous type:

```
var lookup = dictionary
            .SelectMany(p => p.Value, Tuple.Create)
            .ToLookup(p => p.Item1.Key, p => p.Item2);
```

Comment: SO should award a badge for when you beat Jon Skeet with answer ;)

Comment: @3dGrabber "Beat the Skeet" should absolutely be a badge.

Answer (score 1):

Already a few answers here, but putting this here for reference. 
This flips a dictionary with a list of values, to having those values as the keys of look up list.

```
var myLookup = myDict.SelectMany(p => p.Value, 
        (pair, id) => Tuple.Create(id, pair.Key))
    .ToLookup(p => p.Item1, p => p.Item2);
```

Annotated

```
var myLookup = myDict.SelectMany(
        // specify that the select many is to be based off the Value which is a list of items
        p => p.Value, 
        // Using the individual items from that list, create a tuple of that item and the dictionary key it was under
        (pair, id) => Tuple.Create(id, pair.Key))
        // use the item as the lookup key, and put the original dictionary key (that
        // had that value underneath them) in the list of lookup values.
    .ToLookup(p => p.Item1, p => p.Item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer for the question, but I think this is related information and should be posted here.

There is some edge cases you should take into account. All of them about items of dictionary, which have key, but don't have value.

This is expected behavior. Dictionary and Lookup designed for different purposes.

```
var dic = new Dictionary<bool, IEnumerable<bool?>> { [true] = null };
var lookup = dic.ToLookup();

Assert.AreEqual(1, dic.Count);
Assert.AreEqual(0, lookup.Count);

Assert.IsTrue(dic.ContainsKey(true));
Assert.IsFalse(lookup.Contains(true));

Assert.IsFalse(dic.ContainsKey(false));
Assert.IsFalse(lookup.Contains(false));

dic[false] -> Exception
lookup[false] -> bool?[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I think this should work, without needing to enumerate everything again and create temporary tuples/anonymous types.

```
public static ILookup<TKey, TElement> ToLookup<TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TKey> keys,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>> selector)
{
    return new ManualLookup<TKey, TElement>(keys, selector);
}

private class ManualLookup<TKey, TElement> : ILookup<TKey, TElement>
{
    private IEnumerable<TKey> _keys;
    private Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>> _selector;

    public ManualLookup(IEnumerable<TKey> keys, Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>> selector)
    {
        _keys = keys;
        _selector = selector;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TElement> this[TKey key] => _selector(key);

    public int Count => _keys.Count();

    public bool Contains(TKey key) => _keys.Contains(key);

    public IEnumerator<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GetEnumerator() => _keys
        .Select(key => new ManualGrouping<TKey, TElement>(key, _selector(key)))
        .GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

private class ManualGrouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private TKey _key;
    private IEnumerable<TElement> _enumerable;

    public ManualGrouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> enumerable)
    {
        _key = key;
        _enumerable = enumerable;
    }

    public TKey Key => _key;

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() => _enumerable.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Dictionary<MyType, List<MyOtherType>> dictionary;
return dictionary.Keys.ToLookup(key => 
{
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var list)
    {
        return list;
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<MyOtherType>();
});
```