# Convert dictionary with List to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I have a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<String, List<Foo>> test = new Dictionary<String, List<Foo>>();
```

I then populate this dictionary hence why I need the list so I can call Add(). My problem is the function needs to return:

```
Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Foo>>
```

Is there any easy way to do this without doing the obvious and looping through my original dictionary and doing it manually?

Comment: Have you considered using a Lookup instead? That's typically a cleaner way of dealing with this type of thing.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Foo>>` in the first place? How do you populate it? Maybe you can use `ToDictionary` similar as what Selman has used but in the first place when you populate it.

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain without posting a lot of code. I have two different sources that I perform some calculations with and then create a new object, in this case Foo to store the results.

Comment: @DasDave: You should really have a look at a [`Lookup<TKey,TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which you can get from `ToLookup` and which is a  really nice class similar to a dictionary. But it's key doesn't need to be unique, nor does it need to exist and the value is an `IEnumerable<T>` implicitely (empty if the key doesn't exist).

Comment: @DasDave: also, you can always use a `List<Foo>` if you want to use `Add` and finally add it to a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Foo>>` via `dict.Add("foo", list)` since a `List<Foo>` implements `IEnumerable<Foo>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more efficient and easier to use the `List<Foo>` to add things but add it to a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Foo>>`. That's no problem since `List<Foo>` implements `IEnumerable<Foo>`, it's not even necessary to cast.

So something like this(pseudo code):

```
var test = new Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Foo>>();
foreach(var x in something)
{
    var list = new List<Foo>();
    foreach(var y in x.SomeCollection)
        list.Add(y.SomeProperty);
    test.Add(x.KeyProperty, list); // works since List<T> is also an IEnumerable<T>
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
return dictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key,x => x.Value.AsEnumerable())
```

Comment: But it creates a new dictionary by looping the original dictionary which is what OP wants to avoid.

Comment: it's also more efficient and easier to use the `List<Foo>` to add things but add it to a `Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Foo>>`. That's no problem since `List<Foo>` implements `IEnumerable<Foo>`, it's not even necessary to cast.

Comment: @TimSchmelter this is the final result i went for. If you reformat into an answer i will mark as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this route as well, converting `Dictionary<string, List<Foo>>` to a `ReadOnlyDictionary<string, IEnumerable<Foo>>`. While I was trying to convert to a read-only dictionary, the whole purpose of converting a `List` to `IEnumerable` is to make a read only collection. The problem with the OP's approach is:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

errors["foo"] = new List<string>() { "You can't do this" };

Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> readOnlyErrors = // convert errors...

readOnlyErrors["foo"] = new List<string>() { "I'm not actually read-only!" };
```

The appearance of `IEnumerable<Foo>` makes you think this is read only and safe, when in fact it is not. After reading the question [LINQ Convert Dictionary to Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464200/linq-convert-dictionary-to-lookup) a `Lookup` object is more appropriate, because it allows you to:

- Associate one key with multiple values
- You cannot overwrite a key with a new value

  ```
  // This results in a compiler error
  lookUp["foo"] = new List<Foo>() { ... };
  ```
- The "multiple values" are already defined as `IEnumerable<T>`
- You can still use the same outer and inner loop algorithm to extract individual values:

  ```
  ILookup<string, string> lookup = // Convert to lookup

  foreach (IGrouping<string, string> grouping in lookup)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(grouping.Key + ":");

      foreach (string item in grouping)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("    item: " + item);
      }
  }
  ```

### Convert `Dictionary<string, List<Foo>>` to `ILookup<string, Foo>`

It's a quick two-liner:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Foo>> foos = // Create and populate 'foos'

ILookup<string, Foo> lookup = foos.SelectMany(item => item.Value, Tuple.Create)
                                  .ToLookup(p => p.Item1.Key, p => p.Item2);
```

Now you can use the same two-step loop as you would have with a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Foo>>`:

```
foreach (IGrouping<string, Foo> grouping in lookup)
{
    string key = grouping.Key;

    foreach (Foo foo in grouping)
    {
        // Do stuff with key and foo
    }
}
```

Source: [LINQ Convert Dictionary to Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464200/linq-convert-dictionary-to-lookup)

Converting to another Dictionary with an IEnumerable value is like trying to stuff a square peg into a round hole. The more appropriate, and safe way (from an object-oriented standpoint) is to convert your read/write Dictionary to a Lookup. This gives you the true intended safety of an object that is read-only (except for the `Foo` items, which might not be immutable).

I would go so far as to say that most times when a `ReadOnlyDictionary` is used, you could use `ILookup` and get the same functionality.